# Catch change event of datetime control

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

What's the best way to catch the change of value for an HTML datetime input control? I can catch the "change" event, but it fires as you type things in, so if you try to type a year, the event seems to fire with every keystroke.

It seems that "blur" might work, but is that the best way? Or is there a better way of catching when the value changes, that would work in desktop browsers, iOS, and Android? If the users selects a date, I want to make sure it gets caught without them having to click out.

Comment: I would expect “change” to be the best event for iOS users.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Change seems to fire on my iPhone when you tap one of the values, similar to on a desktop browser. I'm on iOS 14, where they changed the user experience, so I don't know how iOS 13 handled it when it had the spinners.

Comment: With the spinner I’m convinced that it would only fire once the value had changed, after the user had pressed “done”.